# How to count total number of matches of regular expression per file on AIX

Tags: grep, aix

`Grep` is usually used to display the lines containing a match of the specified pattern. Is there any way in AIX to display the total number of matches of the pattern in each file searched? That is to say, every match in every line should be counted.

I tried `grep -c pattern filename`, but that only counts each matching line once however many matches it contains.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What output do you want? Each new matching string on a new line? Or something like each matching line with the number of matches? Or just the total number of matches per file?

Comment: i just want total number of matches per file.

Answer (score 4):

`grep -o foo filename.txt | wc -l`

Answer (score 3):

Finding the 3 occurrences of `b.` in this file:

```
$ cat file
a bc d be f
bg h

$ awk '{c+=gsub(/b./,"")} END{print c+0}' file
3
```

The above will work with any awk on any OS (except old, broken awk of course).

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the patterns first, then count the number of matches.

The -o switch will yield each match on a new line.

Then just count the total number of lines.

Something like:

```
grep -o pattern filename | wc -l
```

Comment: Which version of AIX did you test this on? On 7.1 it is not supported.